# How to update sibling records when updated?

Tags: trigger

I want to update all sibling records and itself when updated.

Anyone knows the solutions/workaround or structure-design suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an apex trigger for the same.

1. **After update** event would be used.
2. Make only a **single SOQL** to fetch all the sibling records, but still with **LIMIT** keyword.
3. After making modifications in the list you queried in SOQL, update the list using DML statement.

**Note:** Because you will be doing updates in after update trigger, I would suggest taking measures to avoid recursion in your trigger. Please follow the below link to see how we can avoid recursive triggers.

http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/avoid-recursive-trigger-salesforce/